# Using DriveImage XML to clone small disk to a bigger one

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

So, I have 3 disks in my systems, the one with the OS, an older 1TB disk and a newer blank 2TB disk.

I had the 2TB disk partitioned as a single 2TB partition and formatted.

Then I used DriveImage XML to clone my 1TB disk into the 2TB disk.
After 12 hours, it finished and I ended with a partition in the newer disk that is just 1TB if the disk is seen with Windows Explorer.
If I see the 2TB disk in Windows Disk Management I do see the disk as 2TB volume however, I don't have the option to expand the volume, since it is already 2TB.
So I have the same "free" space as I had in my older 1TB disk :(

I didn't use the raw mode, because I thought raw mode was going to have the non-desirable effect I ended up with!
So, why did I do wrong? or what are the steps needed in order to have the 1TB cloned to a 2TB disk ?

Answer (score 0):

DXML doesn't expand your drive into the free space - Use Easeus Partition Manager Free to expand into that space. http://www.partition-tool.com/

I have never found the Disk Manager to be very reliable when it comes to disk expansion.